# SP 2013 buttons in SP 2010

Tags: 2013, 2010, conversion

[image: SP2013 btn]

Regarding the SP 2013 buttons in the image (the one with hover effect where the shade slides up/down), I have 2 questions here:

1. Can I achieve the same button (with the same hover effect) in SP 2010?
2. If it is not possible, is there a way to create such buttons in SP 2010?

Thanks

Comment: They are called "Promoted Links". :)

Comment: There is no OOB way to achieve that, but certainly you can build it using jQuery and css

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try [Metro UI Tiles](https://metroui.org.ua/tiles.html) to achieve the same effect. They are pretty straight forward to use.

You need to download the [METRO UI Pack](https://metroui.org.ua/) and reference it in like -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="metro.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="metro.js"></script>
</head>
</html>
```

Excerpt from the link above, this is for the exact effect that you want :

```
<!-- Tile with slide-up effect -->
<div class="tile">
    <div class="tile-content slide-up">
        <div class="slide">
            ... Main slide content ...
        </div>
        <div class="slide-over">
            ... Over slide content here ...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>`
```